# How do I assign hostnames for machines on my network?

Tags: osx, hostname, telnet

I'm using Terminal on a Mac running OS X Yosemite. Wondering how I can assign hostnames so that I can run telnet  instead of using the ip address.

Answer (score 0):

Use the '/private/etc/hosts' file. [Example](http://www.mactip.net/how-to-edit-the-hosts-file-on-a-mac/) (works in place of a DNS resolver):

```
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx    hostname.domain hostname
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx    hostname2.domain2 hostname2
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx    hostname3.domain3 hostname3
```